# ArgumentOutOfRange exception on ConfigureAwait(false)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, autofac

I've the following function:

```
var handlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(string));
dynamic handler = _c.Resolve(handlerType);

var test1 = await handler.Run(query);

var test2 = await handler.Run(query).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The first await statement runs fine but the second statement gives me an ArgumentOutOfRange exception. I've really no idea why this is happening.

I'm using Autofac for resolving the my services.

Can you guys please help me with this?

EDITED:

```
   at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Syntax.NameTable.Add(String key, Int32 length)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Syntax.NameManager.Add(String key, Int32 length)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.SymbolTable.GetName(Type type)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.SymbolTable.LoadSymbolsFromType(Type originalType)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.SymbolTable.AddMethodToSymbolTable(MemberInfo member, AggregateSymbol callingAggregate, MethodKindEnum kind)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.SymbolTable.AddNamesInInheritanceHierarchy(String name, List`1 inheritance)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.SymbolTable.PopulateSymbolTableWithName(String name, IEnumerable`1 typeArguments, Type callingType)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.PopulateSymbolTableWithPayloadInformation(SymbolTable symbolTable, ICSharpInvokeOrInvokeMemberBinder callOrInvoke, Type callingType, ArgumentObject[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpInvokeMemberBinder.PopulateSymbolTableWithName(SymbolTable symbolTable, Type callingType, ArgumentObject[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.BindCore(ICSharpBinder payload, Expression[] parameters, DynamicMetaObject[] args, DynamicMetaObject& deferredBinding)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.Bind(DynamicMetaObjectBinder payload, Expression[] parameters, DynamicMetaObject[] args, DynamicMetaObject& deferredBinding)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.BinderHelper.Bind(DynamicMetaObjectBinder action, RuntimeBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject[] args, IEnumerable`1 arginfos, DynamicMetaObject onBindingError)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpInvokeMemberBinder.FallbackInvokeMember(DynamicMetaObject target, DynamicMetaObject[] args, DynamicMetaObject errorSuggestion)
   at System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject.BindInvokeMember(InvokeMemberBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject[] args)
   at System.Dynamic.InvokeMemberBinder.Bind(DynamicMetaObject target, DynamicMetaObject[] args)
   at System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObjectBinder.Bind(Object[] args, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters, LabelTarget returnLabel)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder.BindCore[T](CallSite`1 site, Object[] args)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)
   at Kairos.Services.ImportService.ImportService.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in F:\Sources\BZ\Kairos\Services\Kairos.Services.ImportService\ImportService.cs:line 61
```

Comment: Could you give us the full stactrace? And maybe split up that line over multipile lines (using temporary variables), to get a more precise line/operation of failure?

Comment: @Christopher I've added the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: `RuntimeBinder` makes it clear the issue is in the run-time compilation of the `dynamic` expression. Lacking a [mcve], I can't rule out that there's some problem in your own code, but from what you've posted so far, looks like a bug in the runtime. Of course, lacking a [mcve] it's not possible to comment on what work-around might be suitable either. But, one obvious question is: do you really need `dynamic` here? It's one of the more over-used features in C#, and there's a good chance it's being used inappropriately here as well.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Unfortunately I'm not allowed to share any code of the project I'm currently working on. I think it has to to with a bug in the .netcore framework. I have an other .net 4.5 project where I'm executing the exact same methods and there it is working fine.